# Google Analytics for iOS 3.12 causes huge memory issues

Tags: ios, google-analytics-sdk

I followed the basic documentation for setting up GA (using coocapods), and as soon as my event is fired

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
                                                      action:@"button_press"  // Event action (required)
                                                       label:@"play"          // Event label
                                                       value:nil] build]];
```

the memory usage goes out of control (gigabytes in seconds). Without this tracker code, everything is just fine.

In Instruments those two allocations repeat millions of times, with nothing else in between.

[image: Instruments]

Comment: Google Analytics is up to 3.13.0 now.  Has your problem been solved in the meantime?

Comment: FWIW: I get lots of leaks if I set GAI.sharedInstance.dryRun = true. On 3.13. No leaks if not dryRun.